# Key does not exist - using self signed ECDSA certificate

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, ecdsa, cng

I have an issue with digitally signing an XML message. Requirements dictate that an ECDSA certificate is to be used with a specific curve. Meaning that the RSA and DSA functionality that is provided by the `SignedXml.ComputeSignature(...)` method won't work without creating a custom implementation of the `SignatureDescription`, `AsymmetricSignatureFormatter` and `AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter`.

That being said and without posting lots of code I have created a simple function that should take a certificate and using its public key sign the data using the `ECDsaCng` class as that is what I have used to create the custom implementation mentioned above.

What happens is, even with my custom implementation, that I get an exception thrown "`System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Key does not exist.`". If however I just create a `CngKey` instead of importing it it works. From what I can see this exception is being thrown out of the code that is calling a method on `internal static extern ErrorCode NCryptSignHash(...)` which is in the `ncrypt.dll`

So my question is why an exception is thrown "`System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Key does not exist.`" and how to resolve it.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateSignatureTest()
{
  var request = "Some xml goes here...";

  var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
  store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
  var certificates = store.Certificates;

  var applicableCertificate = certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>()
     .FirstOrDefault(certificate => certificate.Subject.Contains("ECDSA_CERT_NAME"));

  var encryptingKey = (ECDsaCng)applicableCertificate.GetECDsaPublicKey();

  var exported = encryptingKey.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
  var creationParameters = new CngKeyCreationParameters
  {
    ExportPolicy = CngExportPolicies.AllowPlaintextExport
  };

  using (CngKey objCngKey = CngKey.Import(exported, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob)) // This will throw a Key Does Not Exist Exception
  //using (CngKey objCngKey = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.ECDsaP256, null, creationParameters)) // This works...
  {
    //'Convert String to be signed to a byte array
    var data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(request);

    //'Create a ECDsaCng Object
    var ecdsa = new ECDsaCng(objCngKey);

    //'Sign the string
    var bSignature = ecdsa.SignData(data);

    //'Convert Signature to Base64 string for better reading
    var sSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(bSignature);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You fetched the public key.  Then imported it into a new container and called Sign.  Since the private key is required for signing it threw an exception saying that the private key fields are not present.

Why are you cloning the object anyways? Just call `cert.GetECDsaPrivateKey()` and use that object.

Comment: I have tried this             

var encryptingKey = (ECDsaCng)applicableCertificate.GetECDsaPrivateKey();

var exported = ((ECDsaCng) encryptingKey).Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob); Now get a different exception "The requested operation is not supported." I was under the impression that i would encrypt with the public and the receiver would validate against the private key?

Comment: That is how encryption works, yes; but signing is the opposite. The signer uses the private key (which only they have), the verifier uses the public. But I still don't understand why you are cloning the object at all (which won't work for a smart card). `cert.GetECDsaPrivateKey().SignData(...)` (though using statements are good)

Comment: The last comment was an excellent pointer, i took out the cloning and now I can sign and return a signature. My only issue left now is how to apply this to the custom SignatureDescription, AsymmetricSignatureFormatter and AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter implementations to then create the Signature XML Node.

Comment: If they're not obvious at the MSDN/intellisense level; you could always consider the DSA version: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/dsasignaturedeformatter.cs,19